# Create vite plugin for converter specific file into vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite, vite-plugin-development

I am using Vite + Vue, and i want to build vue components from others file, for example, i have file `diff_component.vue.my_ext`:

```
<h1>Vue Component From other file</h1>
```

And i have `Component.vue`:

```
<template>
<div>
  <diff_component/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import DiffComponent from "./diff_component.vue.my_ext"
export default {
  components: {
    DiffComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

I need to convert my `diff_component.vue.my_ext` into vue component, and get something like this:

```
<template>
  <h1>Vue Component From other file</h1>
</template>
<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

How can i do it? Give me pls link to docs or examples pls.

Comment: So, you have the code to do the conversion from `my_ext` to `vue` you just want to know how to tell vite to use your code for `my_ext` to create a `vue` from it?

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes, exactly

Comment: I gather [the documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html) doesn't help? - specifically the [transforming custom file types](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#transforming-custom-file-types) section

Comment: @JaromandaX, Oh, i have not seen it yet ), thanks, i will see it later.